# List files that match a pattern but ignore files that match another pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, ls, patterns

Let's say I have a directory with files a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3. I only want to match files that start with `a` but don't contain `3`. I tried `ls -I "*3" *a*` but it returns `a1  a2  a3`, even though I don't want it to match `a3`. Is this possible with `ls`?

Comment: interesting diverse set of answers here, but an explanation of why   ls -I '\*3' a\*    fails would be edifying.  and/or why is the shell's globbed list not being subsequently filtered by the ignore switch to ls?

Comment: The man page says about the -I option: `do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN`, however it doesn't explain what is meant by _implied_, but I'm guessing it only applies to files that `ls` gets by glob expansions - and `ls` doesn't expand the `a*`, the shell does that.

Answer (score 14):

Just:

```
shopt -s extglob failglob
ls -d a!(*3*)
```

- `shopt -s extglob` activates extended globbing (enables a subset of ksh's extended operators).
- `failglob` it to cancel the command if there's no match rather than calling it with the glob pattern left as is. Without it, that could end up list the file called `a!(*3*)` even though it contains a `3`.
- `a` matches the starting `a`
- `!()` negates the match inside the `()`...
- `*3*` which is `3` and anything before or after it.

---

```
$ touch 1 2 3 a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 aa1 aa2 aa3 a2a a3a
$ ls -d a!(*3*)
a1  a2  a2a  aa1  aa2
```

Answer (score 8):

Existing answers well state the best way to do this with globs; I'll include this because in most cases, `find` is a better option if you want to do scripting or further processing:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'a*' -not -name '*3*'
./a1
./a2
```

You can feed the answer to `xargs` for easy actions, or to a `while read` loop for more complicated things.

Comment: See `!` for the standard equivalent to `-not`. Note that in order to be able to feed it to xargs or read, you need to add a `-print0` and use `xargs -r0` or `whilte IFS= read -rd '' file` (for which you need zsh or bash)

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is

- to list all files that match `a*`
- then delete all lines containing a `3`

The UNIX command is

```
ls -1 a* | grep -v 3
```

`ls -1` shows one file per line.

`grep` normally finds lines that match a pattern but with `-v` this behaviour is inverted, i.e. grep finds line that don't match that pattern.

Comment: Hi Peter! It would be best to explain, in as much detail as is relevant, how your solution works.

Comment: Parsing `ls` is not a goob idea: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`, using the `~` [glob operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators):

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- a*~*3*
```

With `gnu` `ls` you could use two `--ignore` options:

```
ls -I '[^a]*' -I '*3*'
```

the 1st ignores all file names that don't start with `a` and the 2nd ignores file names that contain `3`

Answer (score 0):

As answers before suggest: Yes, it is possible to solve this with *ls*. To me, this particular question also somewhat implies why your solution has not worked out. Therefore, I'd like to give a late contribution on that.
Basically,

```
ls -I "*3" *a*
```

asks to exclude all entries ending in *3*, but in turn includes **explicitly** all files containing an *a*. In fact, **a** uses shell globbing and is expanded **before** the actual command is executed (this does not apply to *"*3"* as this part is quoted). Thus, your command is in your case equivalent to

```
ls -I "*3" a1 a2 a3
```

consequently listing the entry *a3*. Thus, explicit given entries to be listed are overruling entries concerned by *-I*.
From there, I derive, *implicitly* in the sense of the manual means *everything not specified explicitly*, e.g.

```
ls -I "*3"
```

would have excluded *a3* (but shown other considered entries in that directory too, e.g. *b1*).

Comment: Hey @Peregrino69, thanks for your remark. As you figured, I cannot yet comment. On the other side, I found, this explanation is an important addition to answering the question. I have precised this now.

Comment: Agreed mate :-) However Q&A sites work differently from discussion forums. An answer should be self-contained; i.e. if everyone else decides to delete theirs, the OP (or anyone stumbling upon this via web search) should be able to resolve the issue just with your answer alone. Same logic applies here as with links to external sources - link-only answers do get deleted. Check the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help); that'll give a good understanding on how these sites work.